# Image Sharpening Algorithm coded in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.4, python-imaging-library, imagefilter

I was hoping someone could take a look at this sharpening algorithm I devised using PILLOW and explain to me why it is not giving a desirable sharpening effect on images. It really just looks like crap when applied to my sample images. I've worked on this for several days, but haven't made much progress in either improving the quality of the sharpening effect or the efficiency of the algorithm itself. Ideally, I'm looking for a subtle sharpening effect or something that can be scaled easily. I really appreciate any help or insight that can be provided. Here are the sources that I used to come up with this algorithm:

http://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html#Sharpen

http://www.foundalis.com/res/imgproc.htm

```
from PIL import *
from PIL import Image
import os
os.chdir(r"C:")
filter1=9
filter2=-1


def sharpen2(photo,height,width,filter1,filter2):
    for y in range(1,height-1):
        for x in range(1,width-1):

            (r,g,b)=photo.getpixel((x,y))
            r=int(r*filter1)
            g=int(g*filter1)
            b=int(b*filter1)

            (r1,g1,b1)=photo.getpixel((x-1,y-1))
            r1=int(r1*filter2)
            g1=int(g1*filter2)
            b1=int(b1*filter2)

            (r2,g2,b2)=photo.getpixel((x,y-1))
            r2=int(r2*filter2)
            g2=int(g2*filter2)
            b2=int(b2*filter2)

            (r3,g3,b3)=photo.getpixel((x+1,y-1))
            r3=int(r3*filter2)
            g3=int(g3*filter2)
            b3=int(b3*filter2)

            (r4,g4,b4)=photo.getpixel((x-1,y))
            r4=int(r4*filter2)
            g4=int(g4*filter2)
            b4=int(b4*filter2)

            (r5,g5,b5)=photo.getpixel((x+1,y))
            r5=int(r5*filter2)
            g5=int(g5*filter2)
            b5=int(b5*filter2)

            (r6,g6,b6)=photo.getpixel((x-1,y+1))
            r6=int(r6*filter2)
            g6=int(g6*filter2)
            b6=int(b6*filter2)

            (r7,g7,b7)=photo.getpixel((x,y+1))
            r7=int(r7*filter2)
            g7=int(g7*filter2)
            b7=int(b7*filter2)

            (r8,g8,b8)=photo.getpixel((x+1,y+1))
            r8=int(r8*filter2)
            g8=int(g8*filter2)
            b8=int(b8*filter2)

            rfPixel=r+r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8
            if rfPixel>255:
                rfPixel=255
            elif rfPixel<0:
                rfPixel=0

            gfPixel= g+g1+g2+g3+g4+g5+g6+g7+g8
            if gfPixel>255:
                gfPixel=255
            elif gfPixel<0:
                gfPixel=0

            bfPixel=b+b1+b2+b3+b4+b5+b6+b7+b8
            if bfPixel>255:
                bfPixel=255
            elif bfPixel<0:
                bfPixel=0

            photo.putpixel((x,y),(rfPixel,gfPixel,bfPixel))    
    return photo


photo=Image.open("someImage.jpg").convert("RGB")
photo2=photo.copy()
height=photo.height
width=photo.width
x=sharpen2(photo,height,width,filter1,filter2)
```

Comment: The first obvious issue is that `r"C:\"` isn't a valid raw string literal. This code doesn't even run.

Comment: Sorry, I stripped out the actual path that I had in there. Obviously this code won't run on anyone else's computer without some slight modification, but I thought that was obvious.

Comment: Your `i=255` and `i=0` won't do anything, because `i` is independent of `r,g,b`. Define a `clamp` function and call it while generating each individual component.

Comment: ahh, I see that now, however, I just made that change to the code. I'll change it back to what I had originally which avoids that issue.

Comment: OK, the real issue is that you're using a filter kernel that is extreme. If you use floating point numbers for `filter1` and `filter2` you can back it off a bit, but you'll need to do an `int` on the result. The only requirement is that `filter1+8*filter2==1`.

Comment: Changing those values to floating points has certainly made a drastic difference in the resulting image. Thank you. Can you maybe explain the reasoning behind the requirement filter1+8*filter2==1? Does this have more to do with retaining the original brightness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is likely that you're saving the results to the same image you are getting pixel data from.  By the time you get to a pixel, some of its neighbors have been replaced by the filtered data, and some have not.  The error is small at first but adds up.

To fix: save the results to a different image, say filtered_photo.putpixel(...).  You'd have to create a blank filtered_photo first.

Another big problem (mentioned by @Mark Ransom) is that you probably want filter1 = 1.1 and filter2 = -0.1 or something along those lines.  Using 9 and -1 will make most values come out of range.

A better implementation: don't loop over each pixel in python code, use numpy to process the whole image at once, it will be much faster (and shorter code).  The usual implementation of sharpen is to subtract the gaussian-filtered image from the original image, which is a one-liner using numpy and ndimage (or skimage).

Comment: Excellent suggestions. I didn't even think about the problem that occurs when writing over the image being filtered. I'm going to test that out and see how much of a difference it makes.

I don't have any experience using numpy, but I'm absolutely going to research it. The current looping mechanism I'm using is painfully SLOW.